# Local Group Policy in Windows 7 - Roll back to default settings?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

Is there an option in Local Group Policy (LGP) under Windows 7 to switch back to the default settings as they were before *user* changed them in LGP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't an easy way to revert back to the default settings. You can do the following though:

With the Local Group Policy Editor open expand to the following node:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\All Settings
```

and sort by the `State` column. Any policy that is set using that editor will show on top. Repeat the same process for the User Configuration node. If they set anything else in the Windows Settings or Software Settings node you'll have to look at each option and know which one is set or not.

If you are connected to a domain, the domain will override any conflicting settings that are set on the local machine.

To prevent someone from making changes to the local group policy remove their user account from the Administrator group.

Comment: Yeah, I do believe that this is the 'only fast way' to check if there is anything changed in LGP. Thanks, I marked this as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Delete these files:

```
%windir%\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol
%windir%\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol
```

Then run this command:

```
gpupdate.exe /force
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes across this thread, note that MS does not recommend using the

> secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose

mentioned above since it is unsupported:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222

Answer (score 0):

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
```

Comment: Unsupported for Vista and up! Details below.

Answer (score 0):

Run rsop.msc to get the resultant set of applied policies