# How to enable program execution blocked by domain group policy

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, group-policy, exec, domain-security

How can i enable program execution from any path in local computer using `regedit` when it's blocked by domain policy?

I managed to [remove policy restrictions](https://superuser.com/questions/379908/how-to-clear-or-remove-domain-applied-group-policy-settings-after-leaving-the-do) from registry but this one escaped.