# Un-applying Group Policy Change

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-spotlight

I was playing around in Group Policy Editor on Windows 10 (Education edition, fully updated, version 1703) and managed to disable Windows Spotlight. It turns out I liked the rotating lock screen/login screen images and want to get them back!

So, I went through and reset the apparently relevant group policies to `Not Configured` and rebooted; this didn't help. I tried running `gpupdate /force` both as myself and in an elevated command prompt; no dice. I reset *all* group policies to `Not Configured` and tried `gpupdate` and multiple reboots; still nothing. Finally, I went through all the group policies I had changed and set them to the more permissive setting--Enabled or Disabled as appropriate--followed by `gpupdate`s and reboots; no change.

I looked in the registry and all the relevant keys seem to have the values I'd expect for the group policy settings.

`gpresult /R` just gives me a big list of "N/A"

And I'm still stuck with `*Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization.` in **Settings>Personalization>Lock Screen**.

What gives?

EDIT:

Here's my RSoP

```
C:\>gpresult /V


Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
© 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Created on 5/18/2017 at 1:19:46 PM


RSOP data for COMPUTERNAME\AdminName on COMPUTERNAME : Logging Mode
--------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Standalone Workstation
OS Version:                  10.0.15063
Site Name:                   N/A
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\AdminName
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------

    Last time Group Policy was applied: 5/18/2017 at 1:14:11 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      N/A
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        COMPUTERNAME
    Domain Type:                        <Local Computer>

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Local Group Policy

    The computer is a part of the following security groups
    -------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        System Mandatory Level

    Resultant Set Of Policies for Computer
    ---------------------------------------

        Software Installations
        ----------------------
            N/A

        Startup Scripts
        ---------------
            N/A

        Shutdown Scripts
        ----------------
            N/A

        Account Policies
        ----------------
            N/A

        Audit Policy
        ------------
            N/A

        User Rights
        -----------
            N/A

        Security Options
        ----------------
            N/A

            N/A

        Event Log Settings
        ------------------
            N/A

        Restricted Groups
        -----------------
            N/A

        System Services
        ---------------
            N/A

        Registry Settings
        -----------------
            N/A

        File System Settings
        --------------------
            N/A

        Public Key Policies
        -------------------
            N/A

        Administrative Templates
        ------------------------
            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\SQMClient\Windows\CEIPEnable
                Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\InputPersonalization\AllowInputPersonalization
                Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Messenger\Client\CEIP
                Value:       2, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AdvertisingInfo\DisabledByGroupPolicy
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection\AllowTelemetry
                Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\OneDrive\DisableFileSyncNGSC
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\TabletPC\PreventHandwritingDataSharing
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AppCompat\AITEnable
                Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AppCompat\DisableInventory
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SQM\DisableCustomerImprovementProgram
                Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Local Group Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search\AllowCortana
                Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled


USER SETTINGS
--------------

    Last time Group Policy was applied: 5/18/2017 at 12:10:14 AM
    Group Policy was applied from:      N/A
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        COMPUTERNAME
    Domain Type:                        <Local Computer>

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        N/A

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Unknown Reason)

    The user is a part of the following security groups
    ---------------------------------------------------
        None
        Everyone
        Local account and member of Administrators group
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
        CONSOLE LOGON
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        Local account
        LOCAL
        NTLM Authentication
        High Mandatory Level

    The user has the following security privileges
    ----------------------------------------------

        Bypass traverse checking
        Manage auditing and security log
        Back up files and directories
        Restore files and directories
        Change the system time
        Shut down the system
        Force shutdown from a remote system
        Take ownership of files or other objects
        Debug programs
        Modify firmware environment values
        Profile system performance
        Profile single process
        Increase scheduling priority
        Load and unload device drivers
        Create a pagefile
        Adjust memory quotas for a process
        Remove computer from docking station
        Perform volume maintenance tasks
        Impersonate a client after authentication
        Create global objects
        Change the time zone
        Create symbolic links
        Obtain an impersonation token for another user in the same session
        Increase a process working set

    Resultant Set Of Policies for User
    -----------------------------------

        Software Installations
        ----------------------
            N/A

        Logon Scripts
        -------------
            N/A

        Logoff Scripts
        --------------
            N/A

        Public Key Policies
        -------------------
            N/A

        Administrative Templates
        ------------------------
            N/A

        Folder Redirection
        ------------------
            N/A

        Internet Explorer Browser User Interface
        ----------------------------------------
            N/A

        Internet Explorer Connection
        ----------------------------
            N/A

        Internet Explorer URLs
        ----------------------
            N/A

        Internet Explorer Security
        --------------------------
            N/A

        Internet Explorer Programs
        --------------------------
            N/A
```

Could `Local Group Policy Filtering:  Not Applied (Unknown Reason)` be an indicator of the problem?

Comment: See this  https://superuser.com/questions/379908/how-to-clear-or-remove-domain-applied-group-policy-settings-after-leaving-the-do

Comment: I tried several of the options from that post: (a) `gpupdate /force /boot`, (b) checking the RSoP report again...nothing suspicious, (c) deleting that list of registry keys, both for my administrative user and for my unprivileged daily-use account. Unfortunately, the symptoms persist.